# Convert a string into a hash in Perl using split()

Tags: perl

```
$hashdef = "Mouse=>Jerry, Cat=>Tom, Dog=>Spike";

%hash = split /,|=>/, $hashdef;

print "$_=>$hash{$_}" foreach(keys %hash);

Mouse=>JerryDog=>SpikeCat=>Tom
```

I am new to Perl. Can any one explain the regular expression inside the split function? I able to know `|` is used as the choice of both, but I was still confused.

```
%hash = split /|=>/, $hashdef;
```

I get the output

```
S=>pe=>J=>eT=>or=>rm=>,y=>,u=>sM=>og=>D=>oC=>ai=>kt


%hash = split /,/, $hashdef;
Mouse=>Jerry=>Cat=>TomDog=>Spike=>
```

Please explain the above condition.

Answer (score 6):

`split`'s first argument defines what separates the elements you want.

`/,|=>/` matches a comma (`,`) or an equals sign followed by a greater-than sign (`=>`). They're just literals here, there's nothing special about them.

`/|=>/` matches the zero-length string or an equals sign followed by a greater-than sign, and splitting on a zero-length string just splits a string up into individual characters; therefore, in your hash, `M` will map to `o`, `u` will map to `s`, etc. They appear jumbled up in your output because hashes don't have a definite ordering.

`/,/` just splits on a comma. You're creating a hash that maps `Mouse=>Jerry` to `Cat=>Tom` and `Dog=>Spike` to nothing.

Answer (score 1):

```
$hashdef = "Mouse=>Jerry, Cat=>Tom, Dog=>Spike";
my %hash = eval( "( $hashdef )" );
print $hash{'Mouse'}."\n";
```

eval executes a string as a Perl expression. This doesn't use split, but I think would be a good way to handle the case outlined in your post of getting a hash from your string, seeing as your string happens to be well formed Perl, so I've added it here.

Comment: This doesn't work when `strict 'subs'` is in effect. At the very least, errors from the `eval` string should be propagated via `eval $hashdef or die $@`.From a security perspective, it is catastrophic to get into the habit of using `eval` to parse data.

Answer (score 0):

```
sub hash2string {
   my $href = $_[0];
   my $hstring = "";
   foreach (keys %{$href}) {
      $hstring .= "$_=>$href->{$_}, ";
   }
   return substr($hstring, 0, -2);
}

sub string2hash {
   my %lhash;
   my @lelements = split(/, /, $_[0]);
   foreach (@lelements) {
      my ($skey,$svalue) = split(/=>/, $_);
      $lhash{$skey} = $svalue;
   }
   return %lhash;
}
```

Comment: Explain something about what you are trying to say.

Comment: An explanation would be in order.